# PDO vs mysql console - performance-wise

Tags: mysql, pdo, database-performance

I'm using **PHP 5.5** in **CLI** mode and a local **MySQL Server 5.6.20-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1-log - (Ubuntu)**.

I've got a bunch of SQL files containing DDL and DML statements. These statements are meant to upgrade database to the latest version and they need to be executed in order to do their job. None of the statements selects any record to be retrieved, all they do is either changing the structure and/or `INSERT`/`DELETE`/`UPDATE`. The only `SELECT` statements are `INSERT INTO SELECT`s or `SELECT INTO`s. It's mention worthy that each file might contain multiple SQL statements separated by a semicolon.

I've wrote a PHP script to read and execute these SQLs against the database. The problem is that one particular file takes a long time to execute. After analyzing it, I found out that the problem is a `INSERT INTO SELECT` statement which tries to insert around 30k records.

In order to optimize the insertion, I disabled the table keys by `ALTER TABLE .. DISABLE KEYS;` before the insertion and re-enabling it after insertion was done and it worked when I was testing it in a mysql console. But when I went back to my PHP CLI script it took the same time as before.

To make sure I tested executing all of the files with `mysql < file.sql` command. Here's the results:

`PDO->exec();` took more than 1000 seconds.

`mysql < file.sql` took around 2 seconds.

To prevent any misunderstandings, in both of the above ways I'm executing the exact same statements.

Does anyone have any idea why PDO takes much longer that mysql console?